# Gmaps4Rails with OpenLayers gives JS error when marker clicked: this.serviceObject is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openlayers, gmaps4rails

I am having trouble with using OpenLayers in Gmaps4Rails (Gem version 1.5.2.) When I click on a marker I would like to show the typical callout (Infobox). Unfortunately I get the following JavaScript error:

> this.serviceObject is undefined

Firebug calls the line 195 of the file "gmaps4rails.openlayers.js" responsable:

```
return this.serviceObject.addPopup(popup);
```

If I use Google Maps as API provider instead, everything works fine. Showing and hiding the infobox works nicely. This is why I assume that the error must be somewhere in "gmaps4rails.openlayers.js"

I tried on the latest FF and Chrome on Mac.

For reproducing the error in a reduced example, I created a simple HTML page in the public folder of my Rails 3.2 app and directly linked the needed JS and CSS files. To create the HTML page I copied the HTML code of my broken Rails app and reduced it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link href="/assets/gmaps4rails.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.openlayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="map_container"> 
      <div id="map" class="gmaps4rails_map"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://www.openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      Gmaps.map = new Gmaps4RailsOpenlayers();
      Gmaps.load_map = function() {
        Gmaps.map.map_options.provider = "openlayers";
        Gmaps.map.initialize();
        Gmaps.map.markers = [
          {"description":"<p>This shall be in in the popup</p>",
          "id":117979030,
          "lat":39.5715,
          "lng":2.64694}
        ];
        Gmaps.map.create_markers();
        Gmaps.map.adjustMapToBounds();
        Gmaps.map.callback();
      };
      Gmaps.oldOnload = window.onload;
      window.onload = function() { 
        Gmaps.triggerOldOnload();
        Gmaps.loadMaps();
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I could not find a working example of a successful Gmap4Rails–Openlayers integration on the web. Am I missing a mandatory parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug.

Replace:

```
return this.serviceObject.addPopup(popup);
```

with:

```
return this.map.addPopup(popup);
```

I'll push a fix soon, thanks and +1

Comment: Nice. The fix resolves the JavaScript error indeed. Thank you very much. Unfortunately I encounter another problem which is in my opinion a bug: After opening and closing the info box once I can not open it again. I tried Chrome and FF. Please let me know if I should open a new question for this or dou you consider this part of my first problem?

Comment: Mmm, look at my master branch, the same bug makes remove marker fail. This is what leads ro this issue I guess

Comment: See: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/commit/e907fe4d4edbad6705150e0f6f4ab5943cf4e593#L5L197

Comment: True. The master makes things better. But I did not see it at first, as I got trapped by another tiny bug. For closing the info box I used the X icon and then clicked the marker again. This does not open the info box again until you click once outside the marker on the map and then click the marker again. As far as I can see this is not a gmaps4rails but OpenLayers bug. So, thank you very much.